# Pass an image through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Basically I want to pass a image file with ajax on submitting a form and retrieve the image and send it by email as an attachment file:

Here's the **form** :

```
<form role="form" action="" name="devis" id="devis" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="societe">Company</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-md col-md-8" name="societe" value="" maxlength="" id="societe">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="message"><span class="required">* </span>Message</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <textarea rows="5" name="message" class="form-control input-md col-md-8" maxlength="" required="" style="resize:none;" id="message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="input_file">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="image_input_field">Logo</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group uploaddiv">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Parcourir <input type="file" id="image_input_field" name="file">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-actions col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 text-right">
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Annuler" name="" class="btn btn-default" id="reset">
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I can't seem to find what's the error in my code ! Here's the **AJAX call** :

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('image_input_field');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      // console.log(file);

      var societe = $("input#societe").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
           'file': file,
           'module' : 'ajax_data_form',
           'societe': societe,
           'message': message
        },
        cache: false,

        success: function(reponse) {
          if(reponse) {
            alert(reponse);
            // console.log(reponse);
            // jQuery('#devis').trigger("reset");
          } else {
            alert('Erreur');
          }
        }
      });
     });
```

And here's the **ajax.php**:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['module']) && $_POST['module'] == "ajax_data_form" )
{
     var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: Not possible via Ajax.

Comment: @ling.s actually you can with [html5 file API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: @code-jaff is OP using that API?

Comment: @ling.s obviously, since accessing the file from the files array.

Comment: You can find this perfect solution at 

https://github.com/kamleshwebtech/upload-image-by-ajax

Answer (score 18):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pathname,
    data: new FormData($('#devis')[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divider").html(data);
    }
});
```

and get the file data normally in `$_FILES[];`. Because `FormData` is automatically handles the `multipart` header in an ajax request.

Comment: better if you put an explanation how this would solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

can you try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('image_input_field');
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  // console.log(file);

  var societe = $("input#societe").val();
  var message = $("textarea#message").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "file="+file,
        cache: false,

        success: function(reponse) {
          if(reponse) {
            alert(reponse);

            // console.log(reponse);
            // $('#devis').trigger("reset");
          } else {
            alert('Erreur');
          }
        }
      });
 }); });
</script>
```

In ajax.php

just write

```
 echo 'something';
```

Comment: We can't process files via ajax.

Comment: Everybody saying you can´t process files via ajax... 
I always convert the file to base64 string and send it via ajax call.
On the server side, you receive the string and write it to disk. It can be done and it´s simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a Jquery Plugin Called Jquery Form plugin [Link](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)**

I would suggest to simply submit the form using jquery and what ever data you want you can keep them in hidden fields.

```
$("#devis").ajaxSubmit(options); 
return false;
```

The you can easily get the file in the php page like this

```
$ImageTempname  = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'];
$ImageFilename  = $_FILES['ImageFile']['name'];
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type'];
```

and so on.....

Comment: You forgot to mention that `ajaxSubmit` is a jQuery plugin

Comment: Yes I also think that ajaxSubmit can be used. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know already, it is not possible to process file uploads via ajax calls, it will be possible once [HTML5 FILE I/O Api](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) is ready and implemented by major browsers.

You can use jQuery iframe post form plugin to post data in iframe so user experience will be similar to ajax call (partial update of page).

Here is the link:
https://github.com/dogzworld/iframe-post-form

Description: "This jQuery ajax upload plugin creates a hidden iframe and sets the form's target attribute to post to that iframe. When the form is submitted, it is posted (including the file uploads) to the hidden iframe. Finally, the plugin collects the server's response from the iframe."

As mentioned you can send response from the server and display updates on your webpage accordingly.
There has to be a demo page but it is not working as of now.

You can also use it for file uploads.

Calling Example:

```
jQuery('#frmId').iframePostForm({
    json : true,
    post : function () {
        //return true or false
        return true;
    },
    complete : function (response) {
        //complete event
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```